# Caliburn Micro: taking photo in Mango

Tags: windows-phone-7, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to use a task launcher in WP7.1 Mango with the latest version of Caliburn Micro, but my code is not getting called back once the task has completed. Probably I'm doing something stupid somewhere, but I cannot see where. Here is what I did for a sample repro application you can download from:

http://www.filesonic.com/file/2750397005/PhoneTaskTest.zip

1) create a new WP7.1 application;

2) add a Lib folder in the solution, add there CM dll's, and add a reference to them;

3) change the generated files as specified by CM documentation and add a bootstrapper.

Now up to this point everything is OK and the application starts with no issues. I then do the following for taking a photo:

4) add a button in the main page to the view and a corresponding method in its VM, named *TakePhoto*.

5) change the VM as follows:

a) add a readonly *IEventAggregator* member injected in the constructor;

b) add *OnActivate/OnDeactivate* overrides to let the aggregator subscribe and unsubscribe this VM;

c) add the *TakePhoto* method which is just:

```
_aggregator.RequestTask<CameraCaptureTask>();
```

d) derive the VM from interface *IHandle<TaskCompleted<CameraCaptureTask>>* and implement it:

```
public void Handle(TaskCompleted<CameraCaptureTask> message)
{
  if (message.Result.TaskEventArgs.TaskResult != TaskResult.OK) return;
  SetPhoto(message.Result.TaskEventArgs.ChosenPhoto);
}
```

Now, when I click the button the camera task starts in the emulator and I can take a photo; then I'm taken back to my application, but nothing happens and my Handle method is NEVER called. You can just place a breakpoint there to confirm this.
So, what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle `TaskCompleted<PhotoResult>` instead of `TaskCompleted<CameraCaptureTask>`. Because Caliburn.Micro creates the`TaskCompleted<T>` message with the event args of the Task's `Completed` event which is in the case of `CameraCaptureTask` is [PhotoResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.photoresult%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). So you should implement `IHandle<TaskCompleted<PhotoResult>>` and your Handle method should look like this

```
public void Handle(TaskCompleted<PhotoResult> message)
{
    if (message.Result.TaskResult != TaskResult.OK) return;
    SetPhoto(message.Result.ChosenPhoto);
}
```